# Who is this character and how is he related to the plot of time-travelling robots?

Tags: cartoon, big-guy-and-rusty-the-boy-robot

In episode 11 of season 2 of [Big Guy and Rusty the Boy Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Guy_and_Rusty_the_Boy_Robot_(TV_series)) cartoon, during a failed time-travel experiment, the British ended up winning the Revolutionary War, so Lieutenant Dwayne and Rusty decided to travel about 200 years back into the past to fix history.

At some point, they got stuck in that era because their time-travelling ship ran out of juice. But at the very end, around the 20:01 mark, Lieutenant Dwayne (inside the Big Guy robot) says he know someone who might help:

Who is that character and how is he supposed to help two robots to time travel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After Dwayne says that, they went to see Benjamin Franklin, who once demonstrated that lightning is electricity using a kite that was struck by lightning. Dwayne later says that "Ben's kite key must have done the trick" in other words, they recharged the ship using lightning, a la Back to the Future.